# How to change css style of the navbar-inverse in bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-ui

I am going to change color and another css in my bootstrap navbar-inverse. Default color is black, and I want to change it in dark blue. 
My code, I guess, is correct, but unfortunately, nothing had changed.

```css
.navbar {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 100;
}

li {
  margin: 5px 0px 5px 0px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.menu {
  padding: 0px;
}

.navbar {
  border-radius: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.navbar-inverse {
  background-color: #1b365b;
  border: none;
}

.navbar-brand {
  padding: 5px 15px;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-toggle {
  border-color: #fff;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.active>a,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.active>a:focus {
  background-color: #254a7c;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<header>
  <nav class="navbar-001 navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class="container menu-001">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
                                  </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="img/logo.png" alt="logo"></a>
          </div>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
              <li class="active"><a href="#">О компании</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Прайс</a></li>
              <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Услуги <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a href="#">Грузоперевозки</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Аренда автотранспорта</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Аренда спецтехники</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Ремонт автотранспорта</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Грузовой шиномонтаж</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Вывоз мусора</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Продажа топлива</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Аренда земли</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Страхование грузов</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Документы</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
```

The bootstrap html code works correctly, but navbar css code doesn't work at all. But! css code that isn't related to navbar-inverse works perfectly.

Where is my mistake? What did I wrong?

Comment: witch file css you do call firstly ? the bootsrap css or your file css ?

Answer (score 3):

```
.navbar-inverse {
      background-color:#9933ff !important;
      border:none;
    }
```

you can write another css class for the navbar-inverse and write the background-color and put "!important" as it will overwrite the default navbar-inverse in bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

**try this code**
bootstrap class conflict with your code

```
.navbar-001.navbar.navbar-inverse {
          background-color:#1b365b;
          border:none;
        }
```

**or**

```
.navbar-001.navbar.navbar-inverse {
          background-color:#1b365b!important;
          border:none!important;
        }
```